# How to algebraically solve a system of equations?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I am not sure whether this is right place to ask. Here N, L, H, p, and d are parameters. I need to solve this system of equations. Specifically, I need to solve for b(t) and e(t).

```
Variables | t=1    |  t>1  
----------|--------|------------------------  
   n(t)   |  N     |N(1-p)^(t-1)  
   s(t)   |  1     |((1-p+dp)/(1-p))^(t-1) 
   b(t)   |  L     |b(t-1)+p(H-b(t-1))
   e(t)   |(H-L)/2 |e(t-1)+(p(H-b(t-1)))/2
   c(t)   |(1-d)pN |(1-d)pN(1-p+dp)^(t-1)
```

Please help me how should I start this problem to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Since you used a Wolfram-Mathematica tag, perhaps you intend to use Mathematica

```
RSolve[{b[1]==L, b[t]==b[t-1]+p(H-b[t-1]),
        e[1]==(H-L)/2, e[t]==e[t-1]+p(H-b[t-1])/2}, {b[t],e[t]}, t]//FullSimplify
```

which returns

```
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables

{b[t]->H+(-H+L)(1-p)^(-1+t),
 e[t]->((H-L)(-2+(1-p)^t+2 p))/(2(-1+p))}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mentioned that the value of p and d. 0<p<1 and 0<d<1. With this assumption, still I will get the similar solution?

Comment: Giving it all the available information is often important. Assuming[0<p<1 && 0<d<1, RSolve[{b[1]==L, b[t]==b[t-1]+p(H-b[t-1]), e[1]==(H-L)/2, e[t]==e[t-1]+p(H-b[t-1])/2}, {b[t], e[t]}, t] // FullSimplify] provides Mathematica with the extra information and the result appears to be the same.

Comment: I use conjecture method and find different result. Could you please send me steps?

Comment: Mathematica uses RSolve as I showed and gives the result in a single step. There are no "steps" to show. If you have a different result then you can use your original definition and manually calculate b[t] and e[t] for t=1,2,3,4,5. Compare the solution from Mathematica with your solution with your manually calculated values. Which agree and which disagree? The first five values of each should be enough to settle this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that these formulas give recurrent equations - you find values for t = 1 (from  table), then calculate values for t = 2, then for t = 3 and so on

```
b(t) = b(t-1) + p * (H - b(t-1))
t = 1:   L
t = 2:   b(2) = b(1) + p * (H - b(1)) or 
         L + p * (H - L) = L + p * H - p * L
t = 3:   b(3) = b(2) + p * (H - b(2))

Example: L= 2; p = 3; H = 7;
b(1) = 2
b(2) = 2 + 3 * (7 - 2)  = 17
b(3) = 17 + 3 * (7 - 17) = -13
```

Comment: What about t =infinite? How could we solve for e(t)?

Comment: You can get solution for infinite t only if sequence is convergent. Solution for e(t) uses e and b values from previous step.

Comment: Should I need to use the differential equation method to solve this?

Comment: Don't know and doubt due to discrete nature of equations. What is real problem?

Comment: Actually I meant difference equation method.